# remove triggered geofence after transition

Tags: android, transition, android-geofence

I'm trying to remove a geofence after it has been entered in order to stop it re-triggering the enter transition. From a similar question I got this line which works well

```
LocationServices.GeofencingApi.removeGeofences(mGoogleApiClient,getGeofencePendingIntent()).setResultCallback(this);
```

However it removes all of the geofences rather than just the one that has been triggered.

What do I need to do in order to select the proper ID to be removed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to pass the same String used to build the Geofence.

```
String geofenceId = "randomId";
Geofence geofence = new Geofence.Builder()
    .setRequestId(geofenceId)
    ....
    .build();

GeofencingRequest request = new GeofencingRequest.Builder()
    .addGeofence(geofence)
    ....
    .build();

LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(mGoogleApiClient, request, pendingIntent);
```

To remove the geofence, you can use

```
List<String> geofencesToRemove = new ArrayList<>();
geofencesToRemove.add(geofenceId);
LocationServices.GeofencingApi.removeGeofences(mGoogleApiClient, geofencesToRemove);
```

Or you can get the Geofence from the Intent you've received.

```
GeofencingEvent event = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent( intent_you_got_from_geofence );
List<Geofence> triggeredGeofences = event.getTriggeringGeofences();
List<String> toRemove = new ArrayList<>();
for (Geofence geofence : triggeredGeofences) {
    toRemove.add(geofence.getRequestId());
}
LocationServices.GeofencingApi.removeGeofences(mGoogleApiClient, toRemove);
```

Comment: Thank you this is really helpful! 
Sorry for the late reply, I've been out of the country for a few days!

Comment: Very helpful answer. Thanks